# PDO Bind Value as INT?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$query = "SELECT :option FROM `site`.`fish` WHERE `fishid`=:fishid";
    if ($stmt = $connect->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bindValue(':option', $option, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':fishid', $fishid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '<pre>', print_r($rows, true), '</pre>';
    }
```

The following returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => id
        )

)
```

I want it to return [id]=>7
It has something to do with my BindValues... are they not being recognized as numbers?

Comment: Is the value you are binding an actual integer?

Comment: any reason for selecting ":option"? can't you just write `SELECT id FROM...`?

Comment: Do you emulate prepares?

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r sure they are. It doesn't matter though

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well it is in a function so the SELECT $option will be different many times. I guess I didn't need to do anything with that but with fishid, a user can change its value so I thought binding it would have made it safer.

Comment: Binding a value to a place where it can't work does not make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

With prepared statements it is impossible what you are trying to do.

You cannot pass the columns you are about to select as an argument to a prepared statement. The statement will evaluate to something like this:

```
SELECT 'id' ...
```

What will give you a string 'id' rather than a column's value.

Answer (score 1):

This stems from a common misconception about how the placeholders in prepared statements work: they are not simply substituted in as strings, and the resulting SQL executed. Instead, a DBMS asked to "prepare" a statement comes up with a complete query plan for how it would execute that query, including which tables and indexes it would use, which will be the same regardless of how you fill in the placeholders.

The plan for `SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id = :value` will be the same whatever you substitute for `:value`, but the seemingly similar `SELECT name FROM :table WHERE id = :value` cannot be planned, because the DBMS has no idea what table you're actually going to select from.

Your query, of the form, `SELECT :value FROM my_table` can be planned only because the placeholder represents a literal value, not a column name - setting `:value` to the string `'hello'` would be equivalent to `SELECT 'hello' FROM my_table` and just return the string `'hello'` for every row of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

The column name is not a SQL variable (SQL does not support having variables at that place), but it is just a string in PHP:

```
$option = (string) $option;

switch ($option) 
{
    case "id": 
        break;

    default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        sprintf("Invalid identifier: '%s'", $option)
    );
}


if (false !== strpos($option, "`")) 
{
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        sprintf("Invalid column name: '%s'", $option)
    );
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT `%s` FROM `site`.`fish` WHERE `fishid`=:fishid", $option);

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query))
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':fishid', $fishid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    ...
```

Comment: Importantly, if you do this, you *must* first check `$option` against a known list of actual column. Otherwise you have a security risk if `$option` somehow got set to something like `' 1; DROP TABLE site.fish; --'`

Comment: @IMSoP: If the user you use for selecting data can drop tables you have indeed a security risk. Good point.

Comment: `DROP TABLE` is just a simple example of "something bad". Obviously, you should have locked down users, but that doesn't make SQL Injection a non-issue. Even read-only access could be exploited if the query was left wide open.

Comment: @IMSoP: See updated answer. You are right that prepare does not move all out of the way, however thanks to prepare the input is now validated before the query is getting executed. For the domain logic a whitelist of allowed values should be checked against for `$option` earlier.

Comment: re edited answer: Yeah, that would *probably* be safe enough. A whitelist of allowed values would remove any doubt about fooling the database with special characters, though.

Comment: Sure, this is only last line of defence. Just before the string gets ready for prepare.

Comment: My comment was in response to your changed answer. You then edited your comment to agree that a whitelist should be in place (although still don't mention this in the answer). I don't see why it would need to be earlier than the query prepare, though, since that function refers to a particular table and therefore could know what columns exist.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: As written domain logic needs definition, added that.